# Create a datatable with x rows

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I need to create a tabular expression, and save it using the let statement, so I could use it in another query. I.e. something like

```
let syntheticTbl = range x from 1 to 4 step 1 | project x;
traces | join (syntheticTbl) on x
```

However I get semantic error :No tabular expression statement found.

Could you please advise on what is the right way to do that ?

Thanks!

Comment: This should work fine. There's probably another problem. Please share the full query.

Comment: What is meant by "saving" - what UX are you using? It might not be related to Azure Data Explorer service - but to features of Azure Monitor / Application Insights - and in this case the question should be rephrased differently